# Django : cannot retrieve data from database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm currently making my first Django App and have a small but really annoying issue, i.e. I cannot retrieve data from a remote postgresql database. I am sure that I am connected to the good database as I can access it with **pgAdmin** or when I change its name in my **settings.py** for a fancy name, Django tells me that the database does not exist.

Therefore, I think I got some issues in the declaration of the table to use in the database. Basically, the database name is "banana" and the structure to get to the table is `orange.tomato`. My code is the following :

```
class Fruits(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tomato'
```

When I use this class in the shell, it provides me with an empty string which is normal as I asked him to look in the 'tomato' table which do not correspond to the current structure of the database. However I did not find on the Internet how to properly declare my table... When I try to declare it as `db_table = '"orange.tomato"'`, I raise a Programming Exception :

```
django.db.utils.databaseerror syntax error at or near "."
```

Anyone got a clue how to fix this ? I tried to use this class on a local **sqlite3** table and it's working perfectly...

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Comment: In fact, the primary key is a composite key... And as far as I got it, it is not yet supported by Django... Nevertheless, we got troubles with postgresql so we moved to mysql and it is now working ! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

> django.db.utils.databaseerror syntax error at or near "."

I wouldn't use a `.` in the name of a SQL table, so instead of `db_table = '"orange.tomato"'`, I would use `db_table = 'orange_tomato'`